# How to remove a choice from a user within a list using logic in If Statement?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, logic, python-2.x

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = input ("c>")
if c in mylist :
    print c
else:
    print "not in list"

d = input ("d>")
if d in mylist and not c:
    print d
else:
    print "not in list"
```

Please can someone tell me why the logic in the second if statement above doesn't work?
In my head I'm saying "If d is in the list (therefore a valid choice) and it hasn't already been chosen (c) then print d, otherwise print "not in list".

I have already found a solution using .remove (below) but I don't understand why the other way doesn't work?

Many thanks

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = input ("c>")
if c in mylist :
    print c
    mylist.remove(c)
else:
    print "not in list"

d = input ("d>")
if d in mylist:
    print d
else:
    print "not in list"
```

Comment: You meant `if d in mylist and d != c`. Don't use `list` or any Python builtin function as variable name, you wouldn't be able to use that function after that.

Comment: thanks, i didn't use 'list' in my actual code. I had missed the 'd' = not c. Thankyou!